# jQuery equivalent of YUI Lang.sub function

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, handlebars.js, parse-platform

I am learning to work with Parse API and found this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-parse/) which uses handlebars.js for templating. Since I am comfortable with jQuery and have no experience in YUI so I am trying to simply re-write the above tutorial in jQuery.

But I am stuck in the following part:

```
var content = Y.Lang.sub(Y.one('#todo-items-template').getHTML(), {
                        content: item.get('content'),
                        id: item.id,
                        isComplete: item.get('isComplete')
                    });
```

where, `content`, `id` and `isComplete` are fields in Parse web store.

Now, my question is: what is the jQuery equivalent of above [Lang.sub](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Lang.html#method_sub) YUI function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the very basics, adapt or extend to your needs:

```
$.sub = function(str, obj) {
  return str.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/g, function(_, m) {
    return obj[m];
  });
};

console.log($.sub('Hello {foo}', { foo: 'World' }));
//=> Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pulling in the Handlebars JS repository; It's a very popular solution and is very powerful. Since it's popular, it's probably a good idea to learn how to use it since you'll likely be running into again in the future.

Other templating frameworks are listed here: http://microjs.com/#templating